# Oracle Forms - Compile forms on Windows platform - Redirect errors

Tags: oracle, compilation, oracleforms, error-logging

I'm using **frmcmp.exe** (12.2.1.4.0) to compile forms on *Windows*.

I enter the required information thru the displayed form.

Let say I enter a wrong user/password / missing TNS...  An error window will be displayed to show me what went wrong.

When I execute **frmcmp** in the same scenario, but in batch mode (-batch=yes), the utility completes, but it doesn't return any error (e.g. wrong user/pwd / missing TNS) thru the error stream.

It doesn't create a log file, nor it creates an .err file in this scenario.

Looking at the parameters, there's no nothing that sounds like "please log anything in this file".

Is there a way to get the errors back or frmcmp just catch them and hide them from us?

Thanks

Comment: Did FRMCMP create any .ERR file (by itself, not you specifying it)?

Comment: The .err is generated once the compilation is started (valid parameters) and PL/SQL errors are encountered (e.g.  'Identifier not delacred)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a Unix/Linux platform, you need to use the shell script provided (frmcmp.sh) and do not run the executable directly.

Look in the DOMAIN_HOME/config/fmwconfig/components/FORMS/instances/forms/bin

As for errors, if you run in batch mode in a shell the output will appear in the shell.  If you do not run with a shell then you won't see any output.  If you want output show the shell.  You can redirect the shell output using redirection (e.g. > out.log)